# Visio Dock Stencil Window on Right

Tags: vba, visio

I'm trying to programmatically dock a stencil window on the right side of the screen.  I know I can set the WindowState property of the window to visWSDockedRight but if I already have stencils docked on the right, the stencil I'm trying to dock gets its own sub window, rather than just appearing on the stack of other stencils.

While this is almost what I need to do, it's not quite there.  It would be much better if there was some way to add the window into the already-docked windows.

I have a bank of docked stencils on the left side of the screen and another on the right.  I can use Documents.OpenEx to open the stencil docked, but I can't specify which dock to use.

Answer (score 0):

How are you opening the stencil?  If you open it like this, it should just dock itself in the stack of open stencils:

```
    Documents.OpenEx "stencil.vss", visOpenDocked
```

Comment: Using that method doesn't guarantee it will open in the right-hand window dock.  At this point the tool I develop has a fixed set of stencils available, so we actually just manually dock all the stencils, then programmatically hide them.  Then we unhide them when the code would otherwise be opening them.  This guarantees the stencil shows up in the right place.